# SQL parse column string for numerical data and store in separate columns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

I am using Oracle SQL and want to parse from a single column of strings generally like

```
suitjacket 899, height195cm weight80kg male
blazerjacket 1099, height170cm weight65kg female
pants 299, height160cm weight89kgs male
coat 1099, height165cms weight60.5kg female
```

Note that sometimes the units are plural with the extra 's' at the end. How can I extract the `height` and `weight` data into their own separate columns using an Oracle-compliant SQL query?

```
| height | weight |
-------------------
|   195  |   80   |
|   170  |   65   |
|   160  |   89   |
|   165  |   60.5 |
```

I think I have to use either `substring` or `regex`. `substring` doesn't seem appropriate since the data positions in the string are not fixed. `regex` seems better, but I'm not sure how to make the `regex` and then store it in separate columns, one for the `height` and one for the `weight`.

Comment: I see it to be a simple SUBSTR and INSTR use case. I have edited the question and formatted. Voting to reopen the question.

Comment: I see the question is now reopened, see my answer as I suggested SUBSTR and INSTR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a sample setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (field varchar(48));

INSERT INTO tbl (field) VALUES ('suitjacket 899, height195cm weight80kg male');
INSERT INTO tbl (field) VALUES ('blazerjacket 1099, height170cm weight65kg female');
INSERT INTO tbl (field) VALUES ('pants 299, height160cm weight89kgs male');
INSERT INTO tbl (field) VALUES ('coat 1099, height165cms weight60.5kg female');
```

You could use a combination of the regexp_substr and replace functions, like so:

```
select to_number(regexp_substr(field, 'height(\d+\.?\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)) height,
       to_number(regexp_substr(field, 'weight(\d+\.?\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)) weight
  from tbl;
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/index.html#!4/36d553/7/0) of the above.  And here are some references: [regexp_substr](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html), [replace](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php), [regex cheat sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Good luck!

Comment: You don't need `REPLACE()`; you can use specify the sub-expression you want to return in `REGEXP_SUSBTR()`., so: `regexp_substr(s, 'height(\d+\.?\d+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1) as height` (and you should probably explicitly convert to a number after conversion).

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the insight. I edited my answer and the sqlfiddle demo to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Using simple **SUBSTR** and **INSTR** which would be much faster than regular expressions.

Let's see a working test case:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'suitjacket 899, height195cm weight80kg male' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'blazerjacket 1099, height170cm weight65kg female' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'pants 299, height160cm weight89kgs male' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'coat 1099, height165cms weight60.5kg female' str FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT
  8    SUBSTR(str, instr(str, 'height', 1) + LENGTH('height'), instr(str, 'cm', 1) - instr(str, 'height', 1) - LENGTH('height')) height,
  9    SUBSTR(str, instr(str, 'weight', 1)      + LENGTH('weight'), instr(str, 'kg', 1) - instr(str, 'weight', 1) - LENGTH('weight')) weight,
 10    str
 11  FROM DATA
 12  /

HEIGHT     WEIGHT     STR
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
195        80         suitjacket 899, height195cm weight80kg male
170        65         blazerjacket 1099, height170cm weight65kg female
160        89         pants 299, height160cm weight89kgs male
165        60.5       coat 1099, height165cms weight60.5kg female

SQL>
```

Your query(replace table_name with your actual table):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str, instr(str, 'height', 1) + LENGTH('height'), instr(str, 'cm', 1) - instr(str, 'height', 1) - LENGTH('height')) height,
  SUBSTR(str, instr(str, 'weight', 1)      + LENGTH('weight'), instr(str, 'kg', 1) - instr(str, 'weight', 1) - LENGTH('weight')) weight,
  str
FROM table_name
/
```